# How do you drop minimum value in an array?

Tags: java, loops

Basically, I need to get user input for 5 grades, add them together and get the average. I also need to somehow drop the lowest value out of that array before getting the average.

On top of that I need somehow loop ALL that so that it asks at the end "Type true if you want to redo this stuff type false if your done" but I want to find out how to drop the lowest value first

By the way, I haven't "officially" learned how to do arrays or loops yet so all this none sense is self taught.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

class calculateGrades{
public static void main(String args[]){

    int[] grades=new int[5]; //Array for assignment grades
    int sum=0;
    int average;

    Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);

    //This loop is to take in the user input for assignment grade 
    System.out.println("please enter your 5 assignment grades: ");
    for (int fcount=0;fcount<grades.length;fcount++){
        grades[fcount]=keyboard.nextInt();
        }
    //After this loop is done, all the grades are now placed in the 
    //grades array.

    //Find the minimum value in the array.
    Arrays.sort(grades);
    int mn = grades[0];

    //This loop is to calculate the sum of the inputed array.
    for(int counter=0;counter<grades.length;counter++){
        sum=sum+grades[counter];

        }
    //Now that this array calculated the sum of the array we find the average
    average = (sum - mn) /4;

    System.out.println(average);
    System.out.println(mn);

}


}

}
```

So can anyone help me?

Comment: ... best just chose formal style, without any personal references ;)

Comment: Why are there so many questions that involve calculating the average of assignments!!!

Comment: @JoshM Because there are so many tutorials and teachers using that aas introduction ;)

Comment: @JoshM - because it is a *good example* for learning (pre-OO) Java basics on.

Comment: @StephenC Actually it'S a good example to learn *any* language. It teaches how to build up algorithms while you ahve to deal with most language constructs, too (loop, comparison, if, ...). Works in almost any language as an introduction, including functional ones. Is also a good example to introduce recursion later on.

Comment: @JohannesH. I agree.  (Though maybe not for SNOBOL :-) )

Comment: @VexSilver Getting rude doesn't help here though. And Alexei isn't that wrong, you always should keep your questions neutral and in formal style here.

Comment: I actually commented  alot on your questions (just see below), so stop that debate now. It's not taking us anywhere. There are rules on here, and it's quite usual new users are pointed towards them. It's nothign personal, it's just done to maintain a certain quality among all quesitons on StackOvlerflow, so they are usefull for future reference.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of dropping it out of the array, I would keep track of which the minimal value is, and then subtract it from the sum.

Let me know if you have trouble keeping track of the minimal value.

Comment: Note that you cannot actually drop elements form an array in Java, as an Array is fixed length. YOu can copy all other values to another Array, or use a `List` instead (but tha'Ts a little far-fetched for a java beginner I guess).

Comment: Yes, thank you for pointing that out (I just wanted to use his wording)

Comment: don't forget that once you've subtracted the lowest value, to find the average it would be divided by 'grades.length-1', since you've removed a value.

Comment: Ok What you guys are saying is very foreign to me.  How do you keep track of the minimal value?

Comment: @Vex Silver Think about it...you already wrote a loop that looks at the values one by one...you know how to declare variables that can be used to store previous values...I don't want to give you the exact solution so you can at least learn something from this :)

Comment: @VexSilver [SPOILER WARNING] Start with assuming the first one is the minimal value. The loop through all other elements and copare them with the current minimal value you found. If it's smaller, replace the minimal one. If you reached the end of the array, you have foudn the smallest one.

Comment: Well I think I've finally come to a conclusion based on some posts here.  I've finally got it. and tested the minimal value at the bottom. To be perfectly honest I still don't get what you said.  Being resourceful with the internet and some idea pings here and there actually brought the answer out.

Comment: @Vex Silver What is it that you don't understand? How to get the minimum value of the array? Or why subtracting the value works?

Comment: Yea it's hard me to think in program like you guys so when you say loop through all other elements and compare them with the current minimal value I think to myself wth does that mean very much less translating that into code.

Comment: @VexSilver `(sum-minGrade)/(grades.length-1)` is what the suggestion is. Where `sum` is the sum of the 5 grades you calculated and `minGrade` is the lowest grade you saw. This is just math, not thinking in code.

Comment: @VexSilver Actually translating brain to code isn't something anybody can teach you. Trial and error and lots of repetitions is the key here ;) The biggest problem here is: while a brain can solve some non-trivial problems intuitively, a program cannot.

Comment: @trutheality I think he doesn't understand how to calculate that minGrade.

Comment: @trutheality Ok I understand that, but tell me where do you find minGrade.  Is minGrade nothing more than a variable with some sort of java code behind it?  Is it some java utility or w/e that automatically finds the minimal value in an array?   That's what I'm talking about.  grades.length-1 makes sense because that obviously means the length of your grades - 1 but to just say minGrade brings up more questions than answers.

Comment: @VexSilver Look at Johaness' comment. The one that says SPOILER WARNING.   He's trying to tell you how to calculate that minimum. I can edit the answer with the code you need to find the minimum. But try to think it out. He's telling you to loop through the elements (which you already do with the for (...)). Then have a current minimum value (which would be a variable where you store the current minimum). And then do a comparison (an if) and replace the current minimum variable if the current element is lower than it.

Comment: @VexSilver it's a variable that you put the minimum in somehow. There are many ways to get the minimum. Your way is one way (sorting the array and looking at the first element), Johannes gave another way which xp500 explained, there are probably other ways.

Comment: Perfrormance wise, looping and comparing (the simplest approach, the one I mentioned) is O(n), sorting and looking at the frist one is O(n log n) best case and much more complex (unless one uses a ready-made sorting function). There is no need to do so ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String args[]){

int[] grades=new int[5]; //Array for assignment grades
int sum=0;
int average;
string continue = "false";

Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);

do { // start of the program loop
//This loop is to take in the user input for assignment grade 
System.out.println("please enter your 5 assignment grades: ");
for (int fcount=0;fcount<grades.length;fcount++){
    grades[fcount]=keyboard.nextInt();
    }
//After this loop is done, all the grades are now placed in the 
//grades array.


//This loop is to calculate the sum of the inputted array.
for(int counter=0;counter<grades.length;counter++){
    sum=sum+grades[counter];

    }
//Now that this array calculated the sum of the array we find the average
average = sum/grades.length;

System.out.println(average);

System.out.println("Type true if you want to redo this stuff type false if your done");
continue = continue.nextLine(); // takes in a string input from user

} while (continue.equalsIgnoreCase("true")); // it will loop the whole line again when continue is true
}

}
```

you cannot drop an array element out of an array. So do like what xp500 suggested, track the minimum value and subtract from the sum and then divide the grades.length -1 as what mitim said, or just divide by 4 since it's a fixed array of 5.

im using a do while loop to re-loop the whole program in this case.

Comment: That actually gave a good idea with the whole divide by 4 thing since it is fixed at 5. thanks

Comment: `continue` is a special keyword (can't use it as a variable name) and you shouldn't be comparing strings with `==`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to actually drop the value you should use something like an arraylist since as others have mentioned: an array is a fixed length.
If you used an arraylist you could 
    Arrays.sort(yourArrayList) 
and your lowest value should be the first one.